# WP move posts to different path

Tags: posts, urls, blog

I'm looking to have my blog posts under a subdirectory while keeping pages on the root level.
So for example, I want to keep page URLs are like this:

```
mysite.com/pageone
mysite.com/pagetwo
```

But I want all blog posts to be under the blog path:

```
mysite.com/blog/postone
mysite.com/blog/posttwo
```

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the permalinks settings under Settings > Permalinks. They only apply to posts, not to pages.

Custom structure: /blog/%postname%/

Comment: Right, I saw this setting but I thought it would change the base url for everything, not just posts. That works!